# What are the dangers of dynamic SQL, and can they be avoided?

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

We've just been given the following code as a solution for a complicated search query in a new application provided by offshore developers. I'm skeptical of the use of dynamic SQL because I could close the SQL statement using '; and then excute a nasty that will be performed on the database!

Any ideas on how to fix the injection attack?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SearchVenues] --'','',10,1,1,''
@selectedFeature as varchar(MAX),
@searchStr as varchar(100),
@pageCount as int,
@startIndex as int,
@searchId as int,
@venueName as varchar(100),
@range int,
@latitude varchar(100),
@longitude varchar(100),
@showAll int,
@OrderBy varchar(50),
@SearchOrder varchar(10)

AS
DECLARE @sqlRowNum as varchar(max)
DECLARE @sqlRowNumWhere as varchar(max) 
DECLARE @withFunction as varchar(max)
DECLARE @withFunction1 as varchar(max)
DECLARE @endIndex as int
SET  @endIndex = @startIndex + @pageCount -1

SET @sqlRowNum = ' SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY '

IF @OrderBy = 'Distance'
    SET @sqlRowNum =  @sqlRowNum  + 'dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,' + @latitude + ',' + @longitude + ') ' +@SearchOrder
ELSE
    SET @sqlRowNum =  @sqlRowNum + @OrderBy + ' '+ @SearchOrder

SET @sqlRowNum = @sqlRowNum + ' ) AS RowNumber,ID,RecordId,EliteStatus,Name,Description,
Address,TotalReviews,AverageFacilityRating,AverageServiceRating,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Address5,Address6,PhoneNumber,
visitCount,referalCount,requestCount,imgUrl,Latitude,Longitude,
Convert(decimal(10,2),dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,' + @latitude + ',' + @longitude + ')) as distance
FROM VenueAllData '

SET @sqlRowNumWhere = 'where Enabled=1 and EliteStatus <> 3 ' 

--PRINT('@sqlRowNum ='+@sqlRowNum)
IF  @searchStr <> ''
BEGIN

    IF (@searchId = 1)    -- county search
    BEGIN
       SET @sqlRowNumWhere  = @sqlRowNumWhere +  ' and Address5 like ''' + @searchStr + '%'''
    END
    ELSE IF(@searchId = 2  ) -- Town search
    BEGIN
       SET @sqlRowNumWhere  = @sqlRowNumWhere +  ' and Address4 like ''' + @searchStr + '%'''
    END  
    ELSE IF(@searchId = 3  ) -- postcode search
    BEGIN
       SET @sqlRowNumWhere  = @sqlRowNumWhere +  ' and Address6 like ''' + @searchStr + '%'''
    END    

    IF (@searchId = 4)   -- Search By Name
    BEGIN
        IF @venueName <> ''
            SET @sqlRowNumWhere  = @sqlRowNumWhere +  ' and ( Name like ''%' + @venueName + '%'' OR Address like ''%'+ @venueName+'%'' ) '
        ELSE
            SET @sqlRowNumWhere  = @sqlRowNumWhere +  ' and  ( Name like ''%' + @searchStr + '%'' OR Address like ''%'+ @searchStr+'%'' ) '
    END
END


IF @venueName <> '' AND @searchId <> 4
    SET @sqlRowNumWhere  = @sqlRowNumWhere +  ' and ( Name like ''%' + @venueName + '%'' OR  Address like ''%'+ @venueName+'%'' ) '


set @sqlRowNum = @sqlRowNum +  ' '   + @sqlRowNumWhere 


--PRINT(@sqlRowNum)

IF @selectedFeature <> ''
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @val1 varchar (255)
        Declare @SQLAttributes varchar(max)
        Set @SQLAttributes = ''
        Declare @tempAttribute varchar(max)
        Declare @AttrId int
        while (@selectedFeature <> '')
            BEGIN
                SET @AttrId = CAST(SUBSTRING(@selectedFeature,1,CHARINDEX(',',@selectedFeature)-1) AS Int)
                Select @tempAttribute = ColumnName from Attribute where id = @AttrId
                SET @selectedFeature = SUBSTRING(@selectedFeature,len(@AttrId)+2,len(@selectedFeature))
                SET @SQLAttributes = @SQLAttributes + ' ' + @tempAttribute + ' = 1 And '
            END
        Set @SQLAttributes = SUBSTRING(@SQLAttributes,0,LEN(@SQLAttributes)-3)
        set @sqlRowNum = @sqlRowNum +  ' and ID in  (Select VenueId from '
        set @sqlRowNum = @sqlRowNum +  ' CachedVenueAttributes WHERE ' + @SQLAttributes + ')  '

    END

IF @showAll <> 1
    set @sqlRowNum = @sqlRowNum +  ' and  dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,' + @latitude + ',' + @longitude + ')   <=  ' +  convert(varchar,@range )


set @withFunction = 'WITH LogEntries AS (' + @sqlRowNum +  ')

SELECT * FROM  LogEntries WHERE RowNumber between '+ Convert(varchar,@startIndex) + 
' and ' + Convert(varchar,@endIndex) + ' ORDER BY ' + @OrderBy + ' ' + @SearchOrder


print(@withFunction)
exec(@withFunction)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an aside, I would not use `EXEC`; rather I would use `sp_executesql`. See this superb article, [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html),  for the reason and other info on using dynamic sql.

Comment: This article is amazzing. Every Dynamic sql developer should use it.

Answer (score 2):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks).

Also, these:

[Am I immune to SQL injections if I use stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239905/am-i-immune-to-sql-injections-if-i-use-stored-procedures)

[Avoiding SQL Injection in SQL query with Like Operator using parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228476/avoiding-sql-injection-in-sql-query-with-like-operator-using-parameters)

[Can I protect against SQL Injection by escaping single-quote and surrounding user input with single-quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139199/can-i-protect-against-sql-injection-by-escaping-single-quote-and-surrounding-us)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an optimized version of the query above that doesn't use dynamic SQL...

```
Declare @selectedFeature as varchar(MAX),
@searchStr as varchar(100),
@pageCount as int,
@startIndex as int,
@searchId as int,
@venueName as varchar(100),
@range int,
@latitude varchar(100),
@longitude varchar(100),
@showAll int,
@OrderBy varchar(50),
@SearchOrder varchar(10)

Set @startIndex = 1
Set @pageCount = 50



Set @searchStr = 'e'
Set @searchId = 4
Set @OrderBy = 'Address1'
Set @showAll = 1
--Select dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,@latitude,@longitude)


DECLARE @endIndex int
SET  @endIndex = @startIndex + @pageCount -1
;

WITH LogEntries as (
SELECT 
    Row_Number() 
        OVER (ORDER BY 
            CASE @OrderBy
               WHEN 'Distance' THEN Cast(dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,@latitude,@longitude) as varchar(10))
               WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
               WHEN 'Address1' THEN Address1
               WHEN 'RecordId' THEN Cast(RecordId as varchar(10))
               WHEN 'EliteStatus' THEN Cast(EliteStatus as varchar(10))
            END) AS RowNumber,
RecordId,EliteStatus,Name,Description,
Address,TotalReviews,AverageFacilityRating,AverageServiceRating,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Address5,Address6,PhoneNumber,
visitCount,referalCount,requestCount,imgUrl,Latitude,Longitude,
Convert(decimal(10,2),dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,@latitude,@longitude)) as distance
FROM VenueAllData 
where Enabled=1 and EliteStatus <> 3
And 
    (
        (Address5 like @searchStr + '%' And @searchId = 1) OR
        (Address4 like @searchStr + '%' And @searchId = 2) OR
        (Address6 like @searchStr + '%' And @searchId = 3) OR
        (
            (
                @searchId = 4 And 
                    (Name like '%' + @venueName + '%' OR Address like '%'+ @searchStr+'%')
            )
        )
    )
And
    ID in (
        Select VenueID 
        From CachedVenueAttributes 
        --Extra Where Clause for the processing of VenueAttributes using @selectedFeature
    )
And
    (   
        (@showAll = 1) Or
        (@showAll <> 1 and dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,@latitude,@longitude) <= convert(varchar,@range )) 
    )
)

SELECT * FROM  LogEntries 
WHERE RowNumber between @startIndex and @endIndex 
ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy
               WHEN 'Distance' THEN Cast(Distance as varchar(10))
               WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
               WHEN 'Address1' THEN Address1
               WHEN 'RecordId' THEN Cast(RecordId as varchar(10))
               WHEN 'EliteStatus' THEN Cast(EliteStatus as varchar(10))
            END
```

The only thing I haven't fixed is the selection from CachedVenueAttributes that seems to build up a where statement in a loop. I think I might put this in a table valued function, and refactor it in isolation to the rest of the procedure.

Comment: Aside from fixing the possible SQL injection attack, this non-dynamic SQL will quite possibly suffer from using the 'wrong' cached query plan (see parameter sniffing).

Answer (score 0):

I like dynamic SQL for search.

Where I have used it in the past I have used .Net prepared statements with any user generated string being passed in as a parameter NOT included as text in the SQL.

To run with the existing solution you can do a number of thing to mitigate risk.

1. White list input, validate input so that it can only contain a-zA-Z0-9\w (alpha numerics and white space) (bad if you need to support unicode chars)
2. Execute any dynamic sql as a restricted user. Set owner of stored proc to a user which has only read access to the tables concerned. deny write to all tables ect. Also when calling this stored proc you may need to do it with a user with similar restrictions on what they can do, as it appares MS-SQL executes dynamic sql within a storedproc as the calling user not the owner of the storedproc.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that this is a really old post, but when doing things like:

```
    AND
    (   
        (@showAll = 1) 
        OR (@showAll <> 1 
            AND dbo.GeocodeDistanceMiles(Latitude,Longitude,@latitude,@longitude) <= convert(varchar,@range)) 
    )
```

... an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` will usually help pick a more concise plan, as long as it's not going to be executed a thousand times per second or anything.