# SQL Injection and LIKE statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-injection

What would be the best way to stop SQL injection with a `LIKE` statement? So here is a example of the code:

```
string search = Server.HTMLDecode(userEnteredSearchText);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Result WHERE (Keyword LIKE '%" + @search + "%') "
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("search", search));
```

This is what I have been doing other sql statements and it seems like special characters such as `'` and `%` can't break those statements, but I'm guessing with a `LIKE` statement you need to do a escape key or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding SQL Injection in SQL query with Like Operator using parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228476/avoiding-sql-injection-in-sql-query-with-like-operator-using-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry the quotes are off. You do it precisely like you do with everything else, except that **within** the SQL you need to concatenate the `%`'s. Also, `HTMLDecode` is probably not doing you any good here at all, right? What if they want to search in the db for things that contain `"&amp;"`

```
Search = userEnteredSearchText);

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Result WHERE Keyword LIKE '%' + @search + '%'");
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("search", search));
```

So in your example, you were closing the SQL literal to put in `@search`, which is an invalid keyword or variable - you just need to leave that inside the SQL statement.  Other DB's, you need to `CONCAT` the things together. But the bind variable will properly escape the stuff going to the driver.

Comment: Nice thanks! And what do you mean by your HTMLDecode comment? So I always thought when you take in text from the browser into the server, you should HTMLDecode and when you transfer text from the server to browser, you should HTMLEncode?

Comment: When you get data from the request using standard methods, it's already HTTP (not HTML) decoded for you. HTML Decode is for removing HTML encoding - so things like `&amp;` get translated back to `&`. However, under normal circumstances, there's nowhere the user's data will have been HTML encoded. Yes - you should HTML encode when sending dynamic data back, but when you're receiving data, it's not HTML encoded.

Answer (score 4):

The following looks a little cleaner to me.

```
string search = Server.HTMLDecode(userEnteredSearchText);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Result WHERE (Keyword LIKE @search) "
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("search", String.Format("%{0}%", search)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Avoid single quote for sure in the parameters when you are sending a sql query to database.
Remove any special character present in the parameter in the c# code itself.
I would suggest avoid as many special character as possible.

Comment: Downvote is because one purpose of using a parameter is to eliminate the problems with special characters.