# C# simple code to write an INSERT query is giving an exception

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a very basic and beginner problem. I got a 5 line code and I got exception in that.

My database :
[image: Table -> id,name]

It has one table and two columns inside the table viz. id and name.
I made a form.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Nicki\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\Database2.mdf\";Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (id,name) VALUES (1,'" + textBox1.Text + "')", conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

I get the following exception on running the code:
[image]

It says that I have syntax error even though the syntax error is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou!

Comment: Table and Name are probably keywords.  I would avoid using them.  Also, use parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @LarsTech I was wondering this too. I've personally never tried creating a table named `Table` and I can only envision it not being legal. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Try to embed your names between [...]

Comment: There is a very cute [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/) that explains this line of your code: `'" + textBox1.Text + "'`

Comment: If you really want to use 'Table' as the name of you table in SQL server, wrap it in square brackets -- ie: `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (id,name) VALUES (1,'" + textBox1 + "')", conn);`

Comment: Worked now when I used square brackets. Damn.. this was really dumb.

Comment: Please take LarsTech's advice and do not use keywords as identifiers. `Table` is a terrible name anyway. Also study [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228476/) as your command has a serious mistake.

Comment: Please oh please learn about SQL injection and the 'using' statement

Comment: Also worth noting for a new dev- You want to test your SQL queries in SQL Management Studio if possible- this would have flagged immediately as "Table" would have been blue and the query wouldn't have executed without a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a using clause to properly manage resources and use parameters to avoid security problems. It is not recommended to use reserved words as "table". Try this:

```
const string commandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] (id,name) VALUES (1,@Name)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = textBox1.Text;

    connection.Open();
    var rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```